# How to show row numbers on Android ListViews?

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView set with an ArrayAdapter in my Android app. It lists a set of string values. How do I make it show the row number in front of each list item? Like this:

1. One
2. Two
3. Three

Answer (score 5):

Simply print the `position`, its in the `getView`'s first param. Dont forget to +1 becuause `position` starts from 0

Comment: @Joshin For an implementation of the `getView` stuff, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26830505/create-a-listview-with-selectable-rows-change-background-color-of-listview-rows It'll show you an example of how to override the usual `getView`.

Comment: how would I print it in the getView method? how do I change the text in the view item?

Comment: @Joshin **@Alex K** gave you an example, or googling it. (no offense) Remember SO is not a place that someone coding for you, we try to help what we can help, but you work for yourself :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're trying to achieve this,

[image]

If so, here's the working code :

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lv;
    String[] title = {"Windows","Apple","Android" };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);       
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,title);      
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }



}

class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    Context context;
    String[] title;


     CustomAdapter(Context c, String[] title) 
    {

        super(c, R.layout.listitem,title);
        this.context = c;
        this.title=title;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

         LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

                 View row = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);                 
                  TextView titlee = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                  int pos = position+1;
                  titlee.setText(+pos + ". " + title[position]);
                  pos++;
        return row;     
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**lisitem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Title"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is not possible in ExpandedListView