# Android: Listview onClick action for each item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onclick, onclicklistener

I'm creating an internet radio app. It has a list of stations that could be played when onClick on the item. For example

The list:

### #1 FM

### #2 FM

...

The thing is every item (station) has a different URL and I would not want it to be visible to the user. How can I implement it such that when click on the item, it plays the correct station? Kind of like a different onClick for each item in the list.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce but how do i know that is the item im clicking? Do i have to set a case for each item in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make an adapter for the list view.

2) Send 2 array lists to the adapter i.e **i) name of station ii) url of station**

3) while inflating items in your list view show the name from your **i) name of station array list**

4) when user clicks the an item in list view get the item number clicked and find the url from your **ii) url of station array list** and make a network call to that url

Example - there are 3 stations named 1) ONE 2) TWO 3) THREE 
with respective urls 1) urlONE 2) urlTWO 3) urlTHREE

array list (call it stationList or something) will have the names of stations

array list (call it stationUrlList or something) will have the urls of stations

pass both to the adapter of list view. List 1 with names will be used to show the stations name.. When the user clicks say item 2 in the list look for the 2nd item in stationUrlList and make a network call to that Url .. i hope it helps .

Comment: I understand what you mean but i dont know how to use an adapter. Can you show me a sample code? Thanks!

Comment: @BrandonOng you can see some sample code on adapters here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26830505/create-a-listview-with-selectable-rows-change-background-color-of-listview-rows

Comment: its a lot of code to write an example, i would try in sometime and post it if possible as @AlexK suggested there are a lot of tutorials and examles on intetnet about it.. just google ..

Comment: also i would recomend to use the latest Recyclerview that suppors list view and grid view both and is more easy and efficient to implement . i will write a sample code for that for you if i get a little fre time in a while