# ListView With Dynamic Height Rows, Flashing on Scroll

Tags: android, android-layout

Before I ask my question, here is the reference to the code:

Project Code: https://github.com/paimonsoror/RX8Club.com-Forum-Application

The UI Frame Code (Slide Nav, with Content on right):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The content's list view:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/content_parent">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/mainlisttitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/threadTitlePlaceholder"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

    <!--  <com.normalexception.forum.rx8club.view.PTRListView -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mainlistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

The Item's View Object:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.normalexception.app.rx8club.Log;
import com.normalexception.app.rx8club.MainApplication;
import com.normalexception.app.rx8club.R;
import com.normalexception.app.rx8club.WebUrls;
import com.normalexception.app.rx8club.cache.Cache;
import com.normalexception.app.rx8club.dialog.ReportPostDialog;
import com.normalexception.app.rx8club.fragment.FragmentUtils;
import com.normalexception.app.rx8club.fragment.pm.NewPrivateMessageFragment;
import com.normalexception.app.rx8club.fragment.thread.EditPostFragment;
import com.normalexception.app.rx8club.fragment.thread.ThreadFragment;
import com.normalexception.app.rx8club.handler.AvatarLoader;
import com.normalexception.app.rx8club.html.LoginFactory;
import com.normalexception.app.rx8club.preferences.PreferenceHelper;
import com.normalexception.app.rx8club.utils.Utils;

public class PostView extends RelativeLayout {
    private AvatarLoader imageLoader; 

    private TextView username;
    private TextView userTitle;
    private TextView userPosts;
    private TextView userJoin;
    private TextView postDate;
    private TextView likeText;
    private TextView postBox;

    private ImageView reportbutton;
    private ImageView linkbutton;
    private ImageView downButton;
    private ImageView avatar;
    private ImageView quoteButton;
    private ImageView editButton;
    private ImageView pmButton;
    private ImageView deleteButton;

    private WebView postText;

    private Logger TAG =  LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public PostView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_newreply_children, this, true);
        imageLoader=new AvatarLoader(context);
        setupChildren();
    }

    public PostView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_newreply_children, this, true);
        imageLoader=new AvatarLoader(context);
        setupChildren();
    }

    public PostView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_newreply_children, this, true);
        imageLoader=new AvatarLoader(context);
        setupChildren();
    }

    /**
     * Setup the children we contain in this view
     */
    private void setupChildren() {
        username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nr_username);
        userTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nr_userTitle);
        userPosts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nr_userPosts);
        userJoin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nr_userJoin);
        postDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nr_postDate);
        likeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nr_likeText);
        postBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postBox);

        reportbutton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nr_reportbutton);
        linkbutton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nr_linkbutton);
        avatar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nr_image);
        downButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nr_downButton);
        quoteButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nr_quoteButton);
        editButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nr_editButton);
        pmButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nr_pmButton);
        deleteButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nr_deleteButton);

        postText = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.nr_postText);
    }

    /**
     * Inflate the view, this technically only gets called the first time the
     * view is accessed
     * @param parent    The parent of the view
     * @return          An inflated object
     */
    public static PostView inflate(ViewGroup parent) {
        PostView itemView = (PostView)LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.view_newreply, parent, false);
        return itemView;
    }

    /**
     * Setup our view here.  After the view has been inflated and all of the
     * view objects have been initialized, we can inflate our view here
     * @param post      The model we are going to use to populate the view
     * @param position  Get the position of this view on the window
     * @param listener  The listener object to attach to the view
     */
    public void setPost(final PostModel post, final int position, final OnClickListener listener) {
        username.setText(post.getUserName());
        userTitle.setText(post.getUserTitle());
        userPosts.setText(post.getUserPostCount());
        userJoin.setText(post.getJoinDate());
        postDate.setText(post.getPostDate());
        reportbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if(PreferenceHelper.isShowLikes(getContext())) {
            if(post.getLikes().size() > 0) {
                String delim = "", likes = "Liked by: ";
                for(String like : post.getLikes()) {
                    likes += delim + like;
                    delim = ", ";
                }
                likeText.setText(likes);
            } else {
                likeText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } else {
            likeText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // Lets make sure we remove any font formatting that was done within
        // the text
        String trimmedPost = 
                post.getUserPost().replaceAll("(?i)<(/*)font(.*?)>", "");

        // Show attachments if the preference allows it
        if(PreferenceHelper.isShowAttachments(getContext())) 
            trimmedPost = appendAttachments(trimmedPost, post.getAttachments());

        // Show signatures if the preference allows it
        if(PreferenceHelper.isShowSignatures(getContext()) && post.getUserSignature() != null)
            trimmedPost = appendSignature(trimmedPost, post.getUserSignature());

        // Set html Font color
        trimmedPost = Utils.postFormatter(trimmedPost, getContext());
        postText.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        postText.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        postText.getSettings().setAppCachePath(
                Cache.getExternalCacheDir(getContext()).getAbsolutePath());
        postText.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(false);
        postText.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        postText.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        postText.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        postText.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        postText.getSettings().setUserAgentString(WebUrls.USER_AGENT);
        postText.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(false);
        postText.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(false);
        postText.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        postText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
            }
        });
        postText.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // Check if the URL for the site, and if it is a thread or a category
                Log.d(TAG, "User Clicked Embedded url");
                boolean isThread = false;
                if(url.contains("rx8club.com")) {
                    isThread = url.matches(".*\\-\\d+\\/$");
                    Log.d(TAG, String.format("The Link (%s) is %sa thread", url, (isThread)? "" : "NOT "));

                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString("link", url);

                    if(isThread) {
                        FragmentUtils.fragmentTransaction(
                                (FragmentActivity)view.getContext(), 
                                ThreadFragment.newInstance(), 
                                false, true, args);
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
                Intent intent = 
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                MainApplication.getAppContext().startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });

        postText.loadDataWithBaseURL(WebUrls.rootUrl, trimmedPost, "text/html", "utf-8", ""); 

        // Load up the avatar of hte user, but remember to remove
        // the dateline at the end of the file so that we aren't
        // creating multiple images for a user.  The image still
        // gets returned without a date
        if(PreferenceHelper.isShowAvatars(getContext())) {
            String nodate_avatar = 
                    post.getUserImageUrl().indexOf('?') == -1? 
                            post.getUserImageUrl() : 
                                post.getUserImageUrl().substring(0, post.getUserImageUrl().indexOf('?'));

            if(!nodate_avatar.isEmpty()) {  
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(nodate_avatar, avatar);
            } else {
                avatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rotor_icon);
            }
        }

        // Display the right items if the user is logged in
        setUserIcons(this, post.isLoggedInUser());      

        downButton
            .setOnClickListener(listener);

        // Set click listeners if we are logged in, hide the buttons
        // if we are not logged in
        if(LoginFactory.getInstance().isGuestMode()) {
            quoteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pmButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            deleteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            reportbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            quoteButton
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Quote Clicked");
                    String txt = Html.fromHtml(post.getUserPost()).toString();
                    String finalText = String.format("[quote=%s]%s[/quote]",
                            post.getUserName(), txt);
                    postBox.setText(finalText);
                    postBox.requestFocus();
                }
            });

            editButton
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Edit Clicked");

                    // Create new fragment and transaction
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString("postid", post.getPostId());
                    args.putString("securitytoken", post.getToken());
                    Fragment newFragment = new EditPostFragment();

                    FragmentUtils.fragmentTransaction((FragmentActivity)getContext(), 
                            newFragment, true, true, args);
                }
            });

            reportbutton
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Report Clicked");
                        new ReportPostDialog(getContext(), 
                                post.getToken(), post.getPostId()).show();  
                    }
                });

            linkbutton
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Link Clicked");
                        ClipboardManager clipboard = 
                                (android.content.ClipboardManager) 
                                getContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
                        android.content.ClipData clip = 
                                android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("thread link", post.getRootThreadUrl());
                        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), 
                                "Thread Link Copied To Clipboard", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            pmButton
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "PM Clicked");

                    // Create new fragment and transaction
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString("user", post.getUserName());
                    Fragment newFragment = new NewPrivateMessageFragment();
                    FragmentUtils.fragmentTransaction((FragmentActivity)getContext(), 
                            newFragment, false, true, args);
                }
            });

            final boolean isFirstPost = (position == 0);
            deleteButton
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {            
                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = 
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            switch (which){
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:  
                                // Create new fragment and transaction
                                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                                args.putString("postid", post.getPostId());
                                args.putString("securitytoken", post.getToken());
                                args.putBoolean("delete", true);
                                args.putBoolean("deleteThread", isFirstPost && post.isLoggedInUser());
                                Fragment newFragment = new EditPostFragment();
                                FragmentUtils.fragmentTransaction((FragmentActivity)getContext(), 
                                        newFragment, false, true, args);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = 
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                    builder
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete your post?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                        .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener)
                        .show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Append the signature to the end of the user's post
     * @param trimmedPost   The user's post
     * @param signature     The signature to add
     * @return              A full user post
     */
    private String appendSignature(String trimmedPost, String signature) {
        return String.format("%s<br><br>%s", trimmedPost, signature);
    }

    /**
     * Append attachments to the end of this post if they exist
     * @param trimmedPost   The current post
     * @param attachments   The attachments of the post
     * @return              An appended html string
     */
    private String appendAttachments(String trimmedPost,
            List<String> attachments) {
        if(attachments == null || attachments.isEmpty())
            return trimmedPost;

        // Create an html string for the attachments
        String attachString = "";
        for(String attachment : attachments)
            attachString += 
            String.format("<a href=\"%s\"><img class=\"attachment\" src=\"%s\"></a>&nbsp;", 
                    attachment, attachment);

        // Now append to the original text
        trimmedPost = 
                String.format("%s<br><br><b>Attachments:</b><br>%s", 
                        trimmedPost, attachString);

        return trimmedPost;
    }

    /**
     * If the post is by the logged in user, make sure that they can see the edit and 
     * delete buttons
     * @param vi                The thread view object
     * @param isLoggedInUser    True if post is by logged user
     */
    private void setUserIcons(View vi, boolean isLoggedInUser) {
        quoteButton
        .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        pmButton
        .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        editButton
        .setVisibility(isLoggedInUser? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

        deleteButton
        .setVisibility(isLoggedInUser? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
}
```

The Item's View Layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <merge
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:padding="0dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tv_image"
        android:layout_width="16dip"
        android:layout_height="16dip"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/push_pin" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Title Of Thread-->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="@string/tvTitle"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:textSize="12dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<!-- Started By -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_postUser_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_title"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="@string/tvStarted"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="10dip" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_postUser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_title"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_postUser_label"
    android:text="The Thread Starter" />


<!-- Started By -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_lastUser_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_postUser_label"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="@string/tvLastPost" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_lastUser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_postUser"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_lastUser_label"
    android:text="@string/tvLastPostPerson" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_lastUserDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_postUser"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_lastUser"
    android:text="01/01/2014" />



<!-- Rightend Post Counts -->
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/postcount_details"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tv_lastUser">


<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/tv_labels"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="left">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_postCount_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/tvTotalPosts"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_viewCount_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/tvTotalViews"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_myCount_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/tvMyPosts"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/tv_label_values"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_labels"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="right">
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_postCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="5:45"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>          

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_viewCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="5:45"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>      

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_myCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="5:45"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tv_attachment"
    android:layout_width="15dip"
    android:layout_height="15dip"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tv_lastUser_label"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/postcount_details"
    android:src="@drawable/paperclip" />

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/tv_forum_details"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_lastUserDate"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/tv_lastUser_label"
    android:visibility="gone">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_forum_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:text="@string/tvForum"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_forum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="10dip" />
</LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

**Application Background**: This is simply a mobile interface to a forum that I frequent.  It basically uses JSoup to parse the html, and then loads that content into a friendly view for Android users.

**Problem Description**: Each post within a thread is stored as a view called a 'PostView'.  These views are created through the ThreadFragment which is responsible for reading in the contents of the thread and using the array adapter to store and recycle those views.

The issue that I am having is that each of the rows naturally has its own height.  What this causes is the view to "flash" when scrolling as the contents of the "PostView"'s WebView are created/recycled.  Ideally I need a way to save the height of the WebView the first time around so that when it needs to recycle the view it can force that height while it is loading the contents.

Comment: Sorry but nobody is going to take the time to go through every one of those links to examine your code. Also, questions and/or answers which are primarily link-based are of little use to other Stack Overflow users.

Comment: Noted.  Didn't want to litter the page with code incase I was blind to a simple solution that others have gone through.  Supplemental code is there now.  Links for the project are still there incase anyone needs it.  Not sure what else will help, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one approach would be to pass along the height of the TextView along with the data through the ListAdapter. Create a TextView with a visibility of "gone" and an idea of something like layoutHeight:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/layoutHeight" />
```

Load up the TextView with the height that you passed along.

Then, override the `ListView`'s `getView()` method and set the height from there.

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this,receiverList, R.layout.receiver_entry, new String[] { "receiverId","receiverName", "fullPath"}, new int[] {R.id.receiverId, R.id.receiverName, R.id.fullPath}) {
    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView layoutHeightTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.layoutHeight);
        //get the value from layoutHeight and set the height of this view to that...
        return view;
    }
};
```

If it's of any help, here is an example where `getView()` is overriden: [Create a ListView with selectable rows/change background color of ListView rows when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26830505/create-a-listview-with-selectable-rows-change-background-color-of-listview-rows)

This is not a perfect way to do this. Not even close. I'm still not sure why your ListView is blinking, as `wrap_content` should do just fine without blinking.

Comment: Thanks I will have to give it a test.  I believe the 'blinking' is coming from the WebView.  Because when the WebView first loads, it doesn't have any content in it while it is trying to process the HTML.  So because of wrap-content, it drops the height of the view to 0px while it processes the html.  Thats what I am guessing the 'flashing' is.