# RecyclerView : get position and switch to activity

Tags: android, android-intent, onclick, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

How is it possible to get the position of the item which was clicked in the `RecyclerView` row and than make a intent to an activity in the `onClick` method ?
Here is my adapter:

```
public class SergejAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SergejAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Information> data= Collections.emptyList();

    public SergejAdapter(Context context, List<Information> data){
      inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_drawer_custom_row,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder holder= new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Information current=data.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(current.title);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        TextView title;
        ImageView icon;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            title= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listText);
            icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listIcon);
            icon.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = itemView.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Ernaehrung.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
```

Here I just have an `onClick` when one of the images was clicked, but every image has the same intent.

Comment: Check this post out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26830505/create-a-listview-with-selectable-rows-change-background-color-of-listview-rows. It incorporates some of these things into it

Comment: getPosition() is deprecated. You have to use getLayoutPosition() or getAdapterPosition(). For reference https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can get postion from ViewHolder by using `getAdapterPosition()` method. Like in code below:

```
public class SergejAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SergejAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    ...

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // here you use position
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            ...

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I did it with the switch case, works fine.

Comment: Take into account that setting the position manually is redundant or more specific unnecessary work.

Comment: This is wrong. First of all, ViewHolder already has a position so you don't need to add it. Secondly, the position the onBind may not match the position during the onClick (if items moved). Instead, use `ViewHolder#getPosition` to get the up to date position.

Comment: I can't removed my answer so I edited it to proper answer. My solution works to but this is to much better. Thanks

Comment: `getPosition()` is now deprecated and replaced with `getAdapterPosition()`

Comment: `getAdapterPosition()` Working :)

Comment: @Konrad Krakowiak, Even in `onClick()` it will give perfect position? Even if `setTag()` and `getTag()` not used?

Comment: @JimitPatel you shouldn't user setTag() getTag() if you want to "cache" value in view holder just create member in viewholder and set value for this member

Answer (score 1):

Within your `onClick(View v)` you can simply call `getLayoutPosition()` which will return the position where the click happened. Check the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getLayoutPosition()) for further information.

So your code would be something like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(getLayoutPosition()){
       //TODO
    }
}
```

Preferably you should use an Interface to handle the click.

Comment: `getPosition()` is deprecated. Use `getAdapterPosition()` instead.

Comment: @joaquin Instead of `getPosition()` we now have `getLayoutPosition()` and `getAdapterPosition()`. If you wanna have the same effect you should call `getLayoutPosition()` since it maps to the same method stub. `getAdapterPosition()` does something different.

Comment: thanks for the data. I thought that getAdapterPosition() had the same effect.

Comment: @joaquin I'd say 99% of the time it will return the same value, but that's what the docs say to `getAdapterPosition()`: 
*Note that this might be different than the getLayoutPosition() 
if there are pending adapter updates but a new layout pass has not happened yet.*

Answer (score 1):

or you can just add :

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder > {

...
    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public MyViewHolder (View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Element " + getAdapterPosition() + " clicked.");
                }
            });
        }


    }
```