# Get item position of RecyclerView from another class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a `CardView` list containing around 20 cards made using `RecyclerView` and an `Adapter`.

After a Card item is clicked, I want it to start a new `intent` containing another `CardView` list. I can do this, but I also want it to set card colors depending on the card position clicked.

For example -
If card item `Red` is clicked, it should start new intent class and set card colors to shades of `Red` (I can define it).
And similarly with other color card items.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to change the color of the cardview in the new activity or the original one?

Comment: @NikoYuwono The new activity

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the position of `CardView` from `Adapter`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32473804/how-to-get-the-position-of-cardview-item-in-recyclerview) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

First pass your color as a string to your new activity with bundle:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(mContext, YourNewActivity.class);
mIntent.putExtra("color", yourColorString);
startActivity(mIntent)
```

In your new Activity get color from bundle.

```
String color = "#000";
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle != null){
    color = bundle.getString(color,"#000");
}
```

Pass your color to your adapter in your adapter constructor and in adapter find your card view and set background color like below:

```
cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
```

Good luck.

Comment: Can I in any way use a String array here?

Comment: Yesy if you pass your string array in bundle you can get and use in your new activity. But if you pass string array i think you'll need to pass a position too to your new activity.

Answer (score -1):

do it in this way...inside your adapter

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
       //..... your rest code

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("CardPosition",position); //for positiion
                intent.putExtra("CardColor",
                    list.get(position).getColor()); //for value
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

in second activity you can get position of cardview...change method as per your requirement

Comment: `"CardPosition"` `"CardColor"` are these just reference names for other classes?

Comment: no its name of putextra argument...you can get this argument on other activity with these names...like getArguments().getExtra("CardPosition");